# how to get 1 minute price data of a specific time and date from yfinance?

Tags: python, finance, yfinance

I wanna know how can i get **1 minute** gold price data **of a specific time and date interval** (such as an 1 houre interval in 18th october: 2021-10-18 09:30:00 to 2021-10-18 10:30:00) from yfinance or any other source in python?

my code is:

```
gold = yf.download(tickers="GC=F", period="5d", interval="1m")
```

it seems it`s just possible to set **period** while i wanna set **specific date and time intervals**.
thanks

Comment: Data in 1-minute units can only be obtained for 7 days.

Answer (score 4):

Your call to `yfinance` returns a Pandas `DataFrame` with `datetime` as the index. We can use this to filter the dataframe to only entries between our `start` and `end` times.

```
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime

gold = yf.download(tickers="GC=F", period="5d", interval="1m")

start = datetime(2021, 10, 18, 9, 30, 0)
end = datetime(2021, 10, 18, 10, 30, 0)

filtered = gold[start: end]
```

Outputs

```
                                  Open         High  ...    Adj Close  Volume
Datetime                                             ...                     
2021-10-18 09:30:00-04:00  1770.099976  1770.099976  ...  1767.599976    1035
2021-10-18 09:31:00-04:00  1767.900024  1769.099976  ...  1768.500000     467
2021-10-18 09:32:00-04:00  1768.599976  1769.300049  ...  1769.199951     428
2021-10-18 09:33:00-04:00  1769.300049  1770.199951  ...  1769.099976     750
2021-10-18 09:34:00-04:00  1769.199951  1769.300049  ...  1767.800049     549
...                                ...          ...  ...          ...     ...
2021-10-18 10:26:00-04:00  1770.300049  1770.500000  ...  1769.900024     147
2021-10-18 10:27:00-04:00  1769.800049  1769.800049  ...  1769.400024     349
2021-10-18 10:28:00-04:00  1769.400024  1770.400024  ...  1770.199951     258
2021-10-18 10:29:00-04:00  1770.300049  1771.000000  ...  1770.099976     382
2021-10-18 10:30:00-04:00  1770.300049  1771.000000  ...  1770.900024     180

[61 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: thanks . if I wanna have such 1 houre interval data from i.g. 7 or 30 sequential days, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Just modify your `yfinance` download to extend the period and change intervals. You can simply filter for your data within the returned results as long as you have downloaded the correct daterange

Comment: so for 30 days data I should run filtering 30 times by using for loop?! isn t any easier way?

Comment: @muhamad Please take a look on my update. You can pass start and end as a datetime and fetch whatever dataranges you want in the last 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit 2021-10-25

To clear my answer. Question was:

> i wanna set specific date and time intervals. thanks

All you need is in the code documentation.
So `start` and `end` could be date or **_datetime**

```
        start: str
            Download start date string (YYYY-MM-DD) or _datetime.
            Default is 1900-01-01
```

Example code:

> Note: something wrong with timezones, i've tryed to pass correcth timezone with start and end but lib didn't handle it correctly and I was finish with convert it manually)

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import pendulum
pd.options.display.max_rows=10  # To decrease printouts
start = pendulum.parse('2021-10-18 09:30').add(hours=7)  # My tz is UTC+03:00, original TZ UTC-04:00. So adds to my local time 7 hours
end = pendulum.parse('2021-10-18 10:30').add(hours=7)  # Same
print(start)
print(yf.download(tickers="GC=F", interval="1m", start=start, end=end))
```

Result and you can pass whatever datetime ranges you want:

```
2021-10-18T16:30:00+00:00
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                                  Open         High          Low        Close  \
Datetime                                                                        
2021-10-18 09:30:00-04:00  1770.099976  1770.099976  1767.400024  1767.800049   
2021-10-18 09:31:00-04:00  1767.900024  1769.099976  1767.800049  1768.500000   
2021-10-18 09:32:00-04:00  1768.599976  1769.300049  1768.199951  1769.199951   
2021-10-18 09:33:00-04:00  1769.300049  1770.199951  1768.900024  1769.099976   
2021-10-18 09:34:00-04:00  1769.199951  1769.300049  1767.599976  1767.800049   
...                                ...          ...          ...          ...   
2021-10-18 10:25:00-04:00  1769.900024  1770.400024  1769.800049  1770.300049   
2021-10-18 10:26:00-04:00  1770.300049  1770.500000  1769.900024  1769.900024   
2021-10-18 10:27:00-04:00  1769.800049  1769.800049  1769.099976  1769.400024   
2021-10-18 10:28:00-04:00  1769.400024  1770.400024  1769.400024  1770.199951   
2021-10-18 10:29:00-04:00  1770.300049  1771.000000  1769.900024  1770.099976   

                             Adj Close  Volume  
Datetime                                        
2021-10-18 09:30:00-04:00  1767.800049       0  
2021-10-18 09:31:00-04:00  1768.500000     459  
2021-10-18 09:32:00-04:00  1769.199951     428  
2021-10-18 09:33:00-04:00  1769.099976     750  
2021-10-18 09:34:00-04:00  1767.800049     549  
...                                ...     ...  
2021-10-18 10:25:00-04:00  1770.300049     134  
2021-10-18 10:26:00-04:00  1769.900024     147  
2021-10-18 10:27:00-04:00  1769.400024     349  
2021-10-18 10:28:00-04:00  1770.199951     258  
2021-10-18 10:29:00-04:00  1770.099976     382  

[60 rows x 6 columns]
```

PS: with `start` and `end` you do not have limitation to the last 7 days, but still have limit to the last 30 days:

```
1 Failed download:
- GC=F: 1m data not available for startTime=1631980800 and endTime=1631998800. The requested range must be within the last 30 days.
```

## Original

this lib has a lack of documentation. But this is python and as result it some kind of self-documented.

Read definition of download function here
https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/6654a41a8d5c0c9e869a9b9acb3e143786c765c7/yfinance/multi.py#L32

PS this function have `start=` and `end=` params that I hope help you

Comment: Start and end only accept dates. OP has requested the ability between time ranges. This does not answer the question

Comment: @PacketLoss This is not correct. It is accept a datetime. Please take a look on my update.